# Urql config with guest token for SSG on next js

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, server-side-rendering, urql

So I have a project using the latest Next.js 13, React 18, Urql 3, and using typescript

Currently, I have issues when trying to query the urql from the getstaticprops function. My urql request needs a guest token, and I'm storing the token on session storage(other suggestions ?).

It has no issue when the query is running on the client, but I have it when querying inside the function.

My concern is related to the token reading, so the server cannot read the session storage value.

I'm asking what is the better and simplest way to make this work.

- Does use cookies to store guest tokens will make this work?
- Or the configuration that doesn't work?

This is my current config for urql.ts

```
import {
  createClient,
  ssrExchange,
  dedupExchange,
  cacheExchange,
  fetchExchange,
} from "urql";
import { GRAPH_URL } from "@lib/constant/env";
import type { TypedDocumentNode } from "@urql/core";

const isServerSide = typeof window === "undefined";

const ssrCache = ssrExchange({
  isClient: !isServerSide,
});

const client = createClient({
  url: GRAPH_URL,
  exchanges: [dedupExchange, cacheExchange, ssrCache, fetchExchange],
  fetchOptions: () => {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    return {
      headers: {
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
      },
    };
  },
});

const query = async (
  query: TypedDocumentNode<any, object>,
  variables?: Record<string, string | string[] | unknown>
) => {
  try {
    const response = await client.query(query, variables as any).toPromise();
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) console.error(error.message);
  }
};

const mutation = async (
  mutation: TypedDocumentNode<any, object>,
  variables?: Record<string, string | string[] | unknown>
) => {
  try {
    const response = await client
      .mutation(mutation, variables as any)
      .toPromise();
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) console.error(error.message);
  }
};

export { client, query, mutation, ssrCache };
```

And this some of the code for the blog index page

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  await fetchArticlesSummary();

  return {
    props: {
      urqlState: ssrCache.extractData(),
    },
    revalidate: 600,
  };
};

export default withUrqlClient(() => ({
  url: GRAPH_URL,
}))(BlogPage);
```

This is for the fetchArticlesSummary

```
export const fetchArticlesSummary = async () => {
  try {
    const {
      data: { listArticles },
    }: any = await query(getListArticle);
    return listArticles.items;
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }
};
```

I also doing a setup on _app.tsx

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  if (pageProps.urqlState) {
    ssrCache.restoreData(pageProps.urqlState);
  }

  return (
    <Provider value={client}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

I have followed urql documentation about server-side configuration and many others but still don't have any solutions.